# WooCommerce set_taxes() not acting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax

I am trying to make an order programmatically in PHP. However the shipping taxes does not show up correctly.

The documentation https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item-Shipping.html#method_set_taxes says it expects an array and that is what I give to them...

```php
$shipping_lines = [
    "method_id" => $id,
        "total" => [
                    "dhlpwc-parcelshop"=> "10.00"
                ],
        "totalPrice" => number_format((float)$price,2, '.', '')
    ];

    $item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
    $item->set_method_id($shipping_lines['method_id']); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID
    $item->set_taxes($shipping_lines['total']);
    $item->set_total($shipping_lines['totalPrice']); // (optional)
    $order->add_item( $item );

    $order->save();
```

So what is wrong? I also do not get an error in the logs.

Thanks!